# Eclipse Failed to create Java Virtual Machine after changing eclipse.ini file

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, configuration-files

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showlocation
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Xms512m
-Xmx384m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-Xincgc 
-XX:-DontCompileHugeMethods 
-XX:MaxInlineSize=1024  
-XX:FreqInlineSize=1024 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/Prog/Java/eclipse_addons
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-debug
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true
```

This is my eclipse.ini file after I changed it. This is the eclipse.ini file before I changed it:

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I tried changing:
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
    -Xms512m
to
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
    -Xms1024m
with no luck

Comment: Place the part `-vm` in the top of the file, and change `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` to `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/bin`

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that your -Xms parameter (initial heap size) defines a larger heap size than the -Xmx parameter (maximum heap size), you should fix it. If after fixing it the problem remains try to revert to the original eclipse.ini file and apply the parameters one by one to see which is the other 'wrong one'.

Comment: It did not work. Thanks though. I have started trying them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have changed a lot of things in one go.

As a general strategy, I would suggest reverting to the original settings, and then make the changes one at a time, starting with the most important one ... or the one that is most likely to work.